# Background noise for audio using Tensorflow Dataset API

Tags: api, audio, tensorflow, dataset

I am building input pipeline for speech recognition system.
There are some phrases in WAV that I am successfully reading with dataset API (really impressed, it is so easy and fast) and there are some audio files with background noise that i want to mix with my phrases to augment them and make system more robust to noise.

I want to randomly select background noise sample with separate `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle()`, and then mix it with my sample from another `tf.data.Dataset` sample.

How can i concatenate two datasets of different length (bg noises dataset is potentially infinite)? Is `tf.data.Dataset.zip` is suitable here and will work?

**UPD:** `tf.data.Dataset.zip` sucessfully worked but if dataset of noise samples is small you should multiply it so its size equals size of speech samples dataset. If you will not do this resulting dataset will have length of shortest dataset among zipped together datasets.

Comment: Use a language in yr tags?

Answer (score 0):

tf.data.Dataset.zip sucessfully worked but if dataset of noise samples is small you should multiply it so its size equals size of speech samples dataset. If you will not do this resulting dataset will have length of shortest dataset among zipped together datasets.